# How do I skip libraries when debugging java code in VS code

Tags: java, debugging

When I debug java code in VS code it goes to inside the libraries function (Second picture), Which takes too much time. Have any way skip the process?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: set breakpoints and jump to those. Nobody said you need to debug line by line

Comment: Do what @Stultuske or just press the step over button instead of the step into. Maybe you could benefit from a debugging video? Here's one from VS Code themselves: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6cOsxaNC06c